# How to find duplicate array values from PDO fetchall?

Tags: php, pdo

I am working on a reporting dashboard for our company intranet site. The function below is selecting all of the jobs and suffix from a table. I'm using PDO fetchall to retrieve my results. the array looks like:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [JOB] => 197182 
        [SUFFIX] => 002 
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [JOB] => M03001 
        [SUFFIX] => 001 
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [JOB] => 197182 
        [SUFFIX] => 002 
    )
)
```

In this case, the dashboard should have 2 rows, 1 for each job (excluding the duplicate) however how can I search through this array and have it only return a row count of 2 instead of 3? Since there is a duplicate job and suffix I don't want to create a third row with the same job-suffix so it should only be two rows.

```
function row_count() 
{
    $conn = new PDO('odbc:GLOBALTST');
    $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT JOB, SUFFIX FROM JOBS_IN_PROCESS_G');
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    global $count;
    $count = count($row);\\ if I print this out I get 3
}
```

Comment: `array_unique()` ?

Comment: @Jaquarh per the php documentation on array_unique this function isn't intended to work on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: In this case a simple loop and unset tracked duplicates would suffice. But relying on your data layer to take care of it is probably nicer, if it might be a recurring theme you could also create a view for it.

Comment: Why aren't you performing the count in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that on your query side by selecting `DISTINCT` rows of **JOB** and **SUFFIX** column like below,

```
$result = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT JOB, SUFFIX FROM JOBS_IN_PROCESS_G');
```

**OR** if you want on PHP side after selecting rows from table then check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php) , ***But I prefer first one as it is better to get only what you need from DB table.***

Comment: I second the notion that it should be done on the DB end. A good rule of thumb is don't ask for more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in PHP by utilising the `array_column`. [See it working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IgMqe).

```
$unDuplicated = array_combine(array_column(($rows = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)), 'SUFFIX'), $rows);
```

If you want to keep the order, use `array_reverse`.